# use DB::table with some filters conditions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to create a filter using laravel Query Builder.

I have the following code:

```
$queries = array();
$paginate = 10;
$orders = DB::table('orders')->whereNull('deleted_at');

// the filter i want to apply
$from = 2018-06-18;
$end = 2018-06-20;
$orders->whereBetween('orders.created_at', array($from, $end));
$queries['dateRange'] = request('dateRange');

// other filters
...

$orders->leftJoin('order_status', 'orders.OrderID', '=', 'order_status.OrderID')
           ->select('orders.*', 'order_status.Status')
           ->orderBy('OrderID', 'desc')
           ->paginate($paginate)
           ->appends($queries);
```

The problem is that i get an error - is not working. If a haven`t used leftjoin i will probably used like this

```
($orders = Order::query();).
```

How can i use properly the **DB::table** queries with some filters, or is another better solution to this?

**UPDATE**

to be more specific:

this code works:

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->leftJoin('order_status', 'orders.OrderID', '=', 'order_status.OrderID')
        ->select('orders.*', 'order_status.Status')
        ->orderBy('orders.OrderID', 'desc')
        ->paginate($paginate)
        ->appends($queries);
```

this code does not work:

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')->whereNull('deleted_at');

$orders->leftJoin('order_status', 'orders.OrderID', '=', 'order_status.OrderID')
        ->select('orders.*', 'order_status.Status')
        ->orderBy('orders.OrderID', 'desc')
        ->paginate($paginate)
        ->appends($queries);
```

Comment: Can you share your error message?

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$OrderID in view $orders->OrderID......and o on....can`t access the data from $orders

Comment: You should add table prefix to OrderBy in  ->orderBy('OrderID', 'desc').. ie. orders.OrderID

Comment: i have allready tried... the same error :)

Comment: Why are not dates quoted? $from = '2018-06-18';

Comment: i am testing  for those values....the $from and $end are comming from GET request...i

Comment: The error message seems to be on some other line of code... Please make sure what line is causing the error.

Comment: the code is ok. If write a single line (without Method chaining on multiple lines) works: `$orders = DB::table('orders')->whereNull('deleted_at')->leftJoin('order_status', 'orders.OrderID', '=', 'order_status.OrderID')
           ->select('orders.*', 'order_status.Status')
           ->orderBy('OrderID', 'desc')
           ->paginate($paginate)
           ->appends($queries);`

Answer (score 0):

I have changed to this approach and now it works. The problem was i have to specify on another line the paginate:

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')->whereNull('deleted_at');

// date filter
$orders->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(orders.created_at)'), array($from, $to));

$orders->leftJoin('order_status', 'orders.OrderID', '=', 'order_status.OrderID')
           ->select('orders.*', 'order_status.Status')
           ->orderBy('orders.OrderID', 'desc');

// the paginate and appends write on new line :)
$orders = $orders->paginate($paginate)->appends($queries);
```